# Usar request.user para llenar un campo en forms.py

Tags: python, django

Quiero usar el usuario que se encuentra logueado para llenar un campo del archivo `forms.py`.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Meeting
import datetime
import pytz

class MeetingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Meeting
        fields = [
            'host',
            'titulo',
            'descripcion',
            'comienzo',
            'cierre',
            'ciudad',
            'direccion',
            'categoria'
        ]

    def clean(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        now = pytz.utc.localize(now)

        comienzo = self.cleaned_data['comienzo']
        cierre = self.cleaned_data['cierre']

        if comienzo < now or cierre <= comienzo:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Fechas invalidas!')
            
        return super(MeetingForm, self).clean()
```

**models.py**

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    titulo      = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    descripcion = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    host        = models.ForeignKey(Perfil, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='host')
    publicado   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    comienzo    = models.DateTimeField()
    cierre      = models.DateTimeField()
    asistentes  = models.ManyToManyField(Perfil, related_name='asistentes')
    ciudad      = models.ForeignKey(Ciudad, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    direccion   = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    categoria   = models.ForeignKey(Categoria, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    en_curso    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    culminado   = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-publicado']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('meetings:meeting-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**views.py**

```
class MeetingCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = 'login'
    model = Meeting
    form_class = MeetingForm
    template_name = 'meetings/create.html'
```

Lo que quiero lograr es que al guardar el formulario automaticamente use el usuario de `request.user` para llenar el campo `host`. Anteriormente en otro proyecto lo habia hecho de la siguiente manera:

```
class TaskCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Task
    fields = ['title', 'description']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user #Utiliza el id del usuario que se encuentra en la sesion para
                                                #llenar el campo 'user' del formulario

        return super(TaskCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Pero no se de que manera podria lograr lo mismo en un archivo `forms.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma de lograrlo es sobrescribiendo el método save() de tu formulario, para hacer esto primero es necesario pasar el request al formulario de esta manera:

```
class MeetingCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = 'login'
    model = Meeting
    form_class = MeetingForm
    template_name = 'meetings/create.html'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        form_kwargs = super(MeetingCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        form_kwargs.update({"request": self.request})
        return form_kwargs
```

Posteriormente en tu formulario necesitas sacar el request en el método **init** de esta manera:

```
class MeetingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # Tu codigo va aqui

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request", None)
        super(MeetingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Por ultimo necesitas sobrescribir el método save() del formulario, quedándote este de esta manera:

```
class MeetingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        now = pytz.utc.localize(now)

        comienzo = self.cleaned_data['comienzo']
        cierre = self.cleaned_data['cierre']

        if comienzo < now or cierre <= comienzo:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Fechas invalidas!')
            
        return super(MeetingForm, self).clean()


    def save(self, commit=True):
        obj = super(MeetingForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user = None
        if self.request:
            if hasattr(self.request, "user"):
                # Almacenar el usuario
                user = self.request.user
        if commit:
            # Almacenar el usuario en host
            obj.host = user
            obj.save()
        return obj

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request", None)
        super(MeetingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Meeting
        fields = [
            'host',
            'titulo',
            'descripcion',
            'comienzo',
            'cierre',
            'ciudad',
            'direccion',
            'categoria'
        ]
```